# Authentication Azure Blob by Azure AD user principal java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-identity

Is the any way to authentication the blob-storage service by Azure ad user's info (username and password).
I'm using application principal and it's working fine:
Code snipet

```
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .build();
        new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .credential(clientSecretCredential)
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(container)
                .getProperties();
```

And now do we have any change for user's info ?

Comment: You can use [`UsernamePasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.usernamepasswordcredential?view=azure-java-stable)

Comment: But UsernamePasswordCredential requireds clientId and tenantId as well.
I just try to use username and password only